# Naming convention for variables in class constructor

Tags: vb.net, naming-conventions

In the past when I have written classes and constructors, I named the variables in the constructor parameter something different than what would have been stored in the actual class itself.  I used to think this made things less confusing, but these days I think that is actually more confusing.

What I do now is name them the same, and reference the internal variables with `Me.varname`.  Here is a class I just started building.  Is my naming convention incorrect?

```
Public Class BufferPosition
    Public Offset As Integer
    Public LoopCount As Integer

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal Offset As Integer, ByVal LoopCount As Integer)
        Me.Offset = Offset
        Me.LoopCount = LoopCount

    End Sub
End Class
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You could always use a variable type prefix.. Sub New(ByVal intOffset as Integer, ByVal intLoopCount as Integer)

Comment: @DaMartyr, Ah, I used to do that all the time, but was told that is no longer recommended in .NET.  Is that not the case?

Comment: Some people don't like it and it is not necessary, but I find it useful when reading code because then I don't have to hover over it in the SDK or scroll up to find out its declared type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this

```
Public Class BufferPosition

Private _Offset As Integer
Private _LoopCount As Integer

Public Sub New()

End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal Offset As Integer, ByVal LoopCount As Integer)
    _Offset = Offset
    _LoopCount = LoopCount
End Sub

Public Property Offset() As Integer
    Get
        Return _Offset
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _Offset = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property LoopCount() As Integer
    Get
        Return _LoopCount
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _LoopCount = value
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

Comment: It seems to accessing the `_Offset` and `_LoopCount` variables would be less efficient this way?  Typically, I only expand public variables into properties as needed.  Is this the wrong way to do it?

Comment: In my past and current job, they always asked me to use property, so for me it's now a best practice to use them

Comment: Same here, this is exactly how we do it.

Answer (score 0):

Update on Fredou's answer above with reference to the new version (VS2013) :

You just need to write one line to define a property. Example :

```
Public Property Name As String
```

Visual Basic will automatically define an (internal) private variable called _Offset. So, you also don't need to write explicit Get-Set statements. So, in simple words, the above line replaces all of the code below :

```
Public Property Name As String
    Get
        Return _Name
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _Name= value
    End Set
End Property
Private _Name As String
```